# Is Chi Square goodness parametric or non-parametric?

Tags: statistics, self-study

Does Chi Square goodness of fit require normality assumption? Is it a parameteric or non-parametric test? What it its relation with t-test (parametric test) and u-test (non-parametric test)?

Comment: Check this cheatsheet I have prepared sometime ago: https://github.com/mmortazavi/Statistical-Tests-for-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Statistical_Tests.ipynb. I think it answers your question. Tons of materilas out there to learn the basics of its usage like: https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/goodness-of-fit-test/ and  https://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/goodness-of-fit.aspx.

Comment: @MajidMortazavi thanks that helps, but i am not sure of the answer still after I finishing the reading..

Comment: I try to elaborate more then later, if no one else does meantime.